# How to use Gnu assembler Arm system register encoding with .equ or macro's

Tags: assembly, macros, arm64, gnu-assembler, cortex-a

I'm using the GNU Assembler (directly), for Arm Cortex-A system register access (CLUSTERCFR_EL1).  ThIS register name is not recognized by the Assembler, so I needed to use register encoding as follows:

mrs X1, S3_0_C15_C3_0    /*. this works */

I want to use a macro or equ with the name "CLUSTERCFR_EL1", but have not been successful.  The following does not work:

.equ CLUSTERCFR_EL1,  S3_0_C15_C3_0

mrs  x1, CLUSTERCFR_EL1

I've also tried enclosing the S3...0 characters with double-quotes, but this also doesn't work.

Tried the following macro definition as well, but it also fails.

```
.macro CLUSTERCFR_EL1
S3_0_C15_C3_0
.endm
```

Both the .equ method, and the .macro method fail with:

Error: unknown or missing system register name at operand 2 -- 
'mrs x1, CLUSTERCFR_EL1'

Any suggestions?

Comment: `.equ` can only set symbols to numerical expressions, so it won't work.  I'm not completely sure why `.macro` doesn't.  Another option is to run your asm file through the C preprocessor, which `gcc` will do for you if you name your file ending in `.S` (case sensitive).  Then you could do `#define CLUSTERCFR_EL1 S3_0_C15_C3_0`.

Comment: @NateEldredge `.macro`macros can only be used where an instruction or directive is syntactically valid.

Comment: The GNU assembler's design assumes you're going to use it with some other text macro preprocessor like the C preprocessor for single-token substitutions like that.  Unlike NASM's `%define`, I don't think GAS alone can do this.  (@Nate).